# Трансфер данных с одного iPhone на другой

Tags: iphone

У меня два **iphone**а, на одном моя личная сим-карточка на другом была рабочая карточка, соответственно два разных **WhatsApp** аккаунта зареганые на два номера.

Меня уволили и забрали карточку с рабочего телефона, но **WhatsApp** аккаунт функционирует, я могу отправлять сообщения как буд-то с рабочего номера. Но! Я планирую в новый телефон вставить свою личную сим карту и когда я подключу новый номер к **WhatsApp** мои сообщения с рабочего телефона потеряются, а это недопустимо, там много ценной переписки и важных клиентов, к которым я некоторое время планирую писать как буд-то с рабочего номера...

**Вообщем что сделать чтобы иметь два *Whatsapp* аккаунта на одном телефоне?**

Это *iPhone 6*, *Jailbreak* не вариант...

Answer (score 2):

я воспользовался поиском и нашел следуюшее

> **Как восстановить мои сообщения?**
>
> История ваших чатов в WhatsApp не
>   хранится на наших серверах; мы не можем восстановить удаленные
>   сообщения. Вы можете использовать функцию резервной копии в iCloud,
>   чтобы скопировать и восстановить историю своих чатов.
>
> Резервная копия в iCloud Устранение неполадок в iCloud Резервные копии
>   iPhone Отправка по электронной почте
>
> **Резервная копия в iCloud**
>
> Чтобы сделать резервную копию своих чатов вручную в любое время,
>   перейдите в Настройки WhatsApp > Чаты и звонки > Копирование и нажмите
>   Создать копию. Вы также можете выбрать автоматическое копирование,
>   описанное выше, нажав на Автоматически и далее выбрав частоту
>   резервного копирования. Данное действие позволит создать резервную
>   копию чатов и медиафайлов в ваш аккаунт iCloud; вы можете включить или
>   исключить видеофайлы из резервной копии. Создание резервной копии в
>   iCloud может занять некоторое время, в зависимости от вашего
>   Интернет-подключения и объема резервной копии.
>
> Технические требования: У вас должна быть iOS 5.1 или более поздняя.
>   Вы должны быть зарегистрированы в iCloud (Настройки iPhone > iCloud).
>   Для iOS 7: Документы и данные (Настройки iPhone > iCloud > Документы и
>   данные) должны быть включены. Для iOS 8 или более поздней: iCloud
>   Drive (Настройки iPhone > iCloud > iCloud Drive) должен быть включен.
>   Достаточно свободного места в iCloud и на вашем iPhone.
>
> Использование iCloud в сотовой сети Если вы беспокоитесь об
>   использовании ваших сотовых данных, мы рекомендуем вам ограничить
>   iCloud созданием резервной копии в сети Wi-Fi. Чтобы отключить iCloud
>   при действии сотовой связи, перейдите в Настройки iPhone > iCloud >
>   iCloud Drive для iOS 8 и более поздней или Настройки iPhone > iCloud >
>   Документы и данные для iOS 7 и более ранней и отключите Сотовые
>   данные.
>
> Восстановление истории чата из iCloud Чтобы восстановить историю чата
>   из резервной копии в iCloud, во-первых, убедитесь, что резервная копия
>   истории ваших чатов действительно существует в iCloud, пройдя в
>   Настройки WhatsApp > Чаты и звонки > Копирование. Если вы видите дату
>   последнего резервного копирования, то удалите приложение и установите
>   его снова из App Store. После проверки своего номера телефона следуйте
>   инструкциям на экране, чтобы восстановить историю своих чатов. Те же
>   технические требования, что и при создании резервной копии в iCloud,
>   применяются для восстановления из iCloud. Кроме того, для создания
>   резервной копии и восстановления должен использоваться один и тот же
>   номер телефона. Вы не можете восстановить историю чатов другой учетной
>   записи WhatsApp. Если вы используете свой аккаунт iCloud совместно с
>   кем-либо, это позволит вам хранить ваши резервные копии в отдельности.
>
> Устранение неполадок в iCloud
>
> Если у вас возникли проблемы с загрузкой или восстановлением резервной
>   копии из iCloud, то скорее всего это связано не с WhatsApp, а с iCloud
>   аккаунтом.
>
> **Если вам не удается создать резервную копию, попробуйте следующее:**
>
> Убедитесь, что вы подключены к iCloud в Настройки iPhone > iCloud.
>   Убедитесь, что iCloud Drive включен в Настройки iPhone > iCloud. Если
>   у вас iOS 7 или более ранняя, вы увидите Документы и данные вместо
>   iCloud Drive. Если вы пытаетесь создать резервную копию на iOS 7 или
>   более ранней, то убедитесь, что на всех других устройствах, которые
>   привязаны к вашему Apple ID, опция iCloud Drive всегда выключена. Если
>   на любом другом устройстве, использующем ваш Apple ID, опция iCloud
>   Drive включена, то вы не сможете загрузить данные на iOS 7 или более
>   раннюю. Даже если iCloud Drive был ранее включен, а затем выключен, вы
>   не сможете создать резервную копию на iOS 7 устройстве. Вам нужно
>   будет выполнить процедуру обновления до iOS 8 или более поздней, чтобы
>   осуществить резервное копирование. Убедитесь, что у вас есть
>   достаточно свободного места в вашем iCloud аккаунте для создания
>   резервной копии. Вы можете посмотреть сколько свободного места в вашем
>   iCloud, перейдя в Настройки iPhone > iCloud > Хранилище. Если вы
>   пытаетесь создать резервную копию, используя сотовую сеть, убедитесь,
>   что опция Сотовые данные включена, перейдя в Настройки iPhone > iCloud
>
> > iCloud Drive для iOS 8 и более поздней или Настройки iPhone > iCloud > Документы и данные для iOS 7 и более ранней. Создайте резервную копию вручную, нажав "Создать копию", перейдя в WhatsApp > Настройки >
> >     Чаты и звонки > Копирование и держите WhatsApp открытым до тех пор,
> >     пока на экране видно "загрузка". Создайте резервную копию вручную,
> >     подключившись к другой сети - лучше к той, к которой вы подключаетесь
> >     чаще всего. iCloud работает лучше всего тогда, когда вы создаете
> >     резервную копию из того места, откуда вы чаще всего подключаетесь.
> >     Если вам не удается осуществить восстановление резервной копии,
> >     попробуйте следующее:
>
> Убедитесь, что вы пытаетесь восстановить данные для того же номера
>   телефона и iCloud аккаунта, для которого резервное копирование было
>   осуществлено. Убедитесь, что на вашем iPhone достаточно свободного
>   места для восстановления резервной копии. Вы можете посмотреть сколько
>   свободного места на вашем телефоне, перейдите в Настройки iPhone >
>   Основные > Об этом устройстве. Убедитесь, что iCloud Drive включен,
>   для этого перейдите в Настройки iPhone > iCloud > iCloud Drive. Если
>   на вашем телефоне установлена iOS 7 или более ранняя, вместо iCloud
>   Drive вы увидите Документы и данные. Если резервная копия была создана
>   при использовании iCloud Drive, вы не сможете восстановить данную
>   резервную копию на любом другом устройстве без iOS 8 или более
>   поздней. Если на любом другом устройстве, использующем ваш Apple ID,
>   опция iCloud Drive включена, то вы не сможете восстановить данные на
>   своем iPhone, если на нем не установлена iOS 8. Выполните
>   восстановление, подключившись к другой сети - лучше к той, к которой
>   вы подключаетесь чаще всего. iCloud работает лучше всего тогда, когда
>   вы выполняете восстановление из того места, откуда вы чаще всего
>   подключаетесь.
>
> **Резервные копии iPhone**
>
> Если вы ранее делали резервную копию своего iPhone, используя iTunes
>   или iCloud, то вы можете восстановить свои чаты в WhatsApp,
>   восстановив свой iPhone из предыдущей резервной копии в iPhone.
>   Узнайте больше, как скопировать и восстановить свой iPhone, прочитав
>   данную страницу службы поддержки Apple.
>
> **Отправка по электронной почте**
>
> Вы можете также отправить себе по электронной почте историю чатов,
>   если вы хотите сохранить переписку:
>
> Откройте в WhatsApp чат, который вы хотите отправить по электронной
>   почте. Нажмите на имя контакта или на тему группы в панели навигации.
>   Прокрутите вниз и выберите Отправить чат по почте. Выберите С файлами
>   или Без файлов. Введите адрес электронной почты и нажмите Отправить.
>
> Удачи,  Служба поддержки WhatsApp

[ссылка на эту инфу](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/ru/iphone/20888066)

и второе что нужно

> **Как изменить номер телефона в WhatsApp?**
>
> Если вы изменили свой
>   телефонный номер и продолжаете использовать тот же iPhone, вы можете
>   изменить свой телефонный номер в WhatsApp. Перед этим убедитесь, что
>   ваш новый телефонный номер активирован, и вы можете принимать SMS и
>   телефонные звонки.
>
> Данный процесс предполагает:
>
> Удаление учетной записи, привязанной к вашему предыдущему телефонному
>   номеру, поэтому ваши контакты не смогут больше видеть ваш прежний
>   номер в своих списках контактов WhatsApp. Перенос данных об оплате,
>   групп, профиля и истории чатов в учетную запись, привязанную к новому
>   телефонному номеру. Выполните следующие действия, чтобы изменить
>   телефонный номер вашей учетной записи:
>
> Перейдите в Настройки > Учетная запись > Изменить номер. Введите свой
>   текущий телефонный номер в WhatsApp в первое поле. Введите свой новый
>   телефонный номер во второе поле. Выберите Готово, чтобы продолжить.
>
> После успешного подтверждения вашего нового номера, информация о вашей
>   предыдущей учетной записи будет перенесена на новый номер. Убедитесь,
>   что ваши контакты в WhatsApp сохранили ваш новый телефонный номер в
>   адресных книгах своих телефонов, чтобы вы могли беспрепятственно
>   общаться.

[ссылка на статью](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/ru/iphone/24881042)